# aligning text level of text and parbox where text is wrapped

Tags: parbox

I would like this:

[image]

With the Tex code at the bottom I obtain this:

[image]

Tex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

Text1  \> \parbox{0.8\textwidth}{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}

\end{document}
```

I need some assistance, with a task which should be trivial, namely to have "Text1" and "bla bla bla [...]" to begin in the same line level.

NB. I already used a lot of time to figure out the parbox could wrap the text in the "tab-enviroment" - even though this should also be relatively simple.

Comment: try `\parbox[t]{0.8\textwidth}{...}` (observe `[t]`)

Comment: Thank you, this was the quickfix I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anchor the `\parbox` at the `[t]`op:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Text1  \> \parbox{0.8\textwidth}{\strut bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla\strut}

Text1  \> \parbox[t]{0.8\textwidth}{\strut bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla\strut}

\end{document}
```

Adding a `\strut` to the start/end of a `\parbox` ensures proper alignment with the baselines for surrounding structures.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution I was seeking.